# Build Boost Regex for Windows VS2013

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I need only Boost Regex libraries which are not header-only. I am using Boost 1_67_0 on Visual Studio 2013. I also need to build this library both for x86 and x64. I have gone through the steps to build boost, but unable to find out the exact way to build just this library.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have bootstrapped and have a `b2.exe`. Running `b2 --help` should help. The particular command I would usually use is `b2 --with-regex stage`.

I think newer version of Boost by default should build both debug and release 32-bit and 64-bit libs, but if it doesn't then you could try adding `address-model=32,64` to the command.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. Just wondering how to specify VS 2013 Update 5 because it picked up VS2017 (VC14.1) even though I was in the native prompt for VS 2013.

Comment: Try `toolset=msvc-12.0`